# How can I make the input fields show up in the center? Text-align: center; does not work

Tags: html, css

I am very new to web development. This is actually my first personal project and I'm having trouble aligning the input fields. I designed the layout in XD and trying to code the design. Keep in mind, I'm working on the mobile layout so its only about 400 pixels wide. I guess I can worry about the responsiveness later with media queries. Anyway, I've tried targeting the input fields and using **text-align: center;** but it's not working. Please help!

This is what my page currently looks like:

[image: enter image description here]]

This is what I need it to look like:

[image: This is what I need them to look like]]

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,300i,400,400i,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

    <title>40 Hour Workweek Calculator</title>

</head>
<header>
  <h3>40-Hour Workweek Calculator</h3>
</header>

<body>
    <h4 class="sections">Total hours needed to work this week:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 40" />

    <h4 class="sections">On Friday morning, how many hours<br />(in whole numbers) do you currently have?</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 33"/>

    <h4 class="sections">Enter remaining decimals:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: .57"/>

    <h4 class="sections">Converted to time format:</h4>
      <div class="defaultCalc"></div>

    <h4 class="sections">Remaining hours to work:</h4>
      <div class="defaultCalc"></div>

    <h4 class="sections">Enter time you clocked in on Friday:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 7:22"/><br />

<div class="buttons">
    <button class="amButton">AM</button>
    <button class="pmButton">PM</button>
</div>

    <h4 class="sections">Enter today's lunch break in minutes:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 30"/>

<div class="sections">
    <button class="calcButton">Calculate my hours</button>

<h4 class="sections">Time to clock out on Friday:</h4>
    <div class="defaultCalc clockOutTime"></div>

<div class="sections">
    <div class="clockOutAMButton">AM</div>
    <div class="clockOutPMButton">PM</div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
/*Base style layouts*/

header, body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #edf0f1;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 46px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 46px;
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44,62,80,0.15);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #95989A;
  text-align: center;
}

.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
}


/*Gray areas that display javascript calculations*/

.defaultCalc {
  border: 1px none;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}


/*Sections that require the user to input a number*/
.userInput::placeholder {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgba(149, 152, 154, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
}

.userInput {
  border: 1px solid #D3D8DB;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}


.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

/*Buttons*/

.amButton,
.pmButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.calcButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 217px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.clockOutTime {
  border: 1px none;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #60B6FF;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.clockOutAMButton,
.clockOutPMButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
}

button:focus {outline:0;}

input:focus {
  border-color: #15D1BC;
  outline: none;
}

.pmButton:focus {
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.amButton:focus {
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.calcButton:active {
  font-size: 1.075em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the `input`s you want to use `text-align: center` on the **parent**. You could either introduce a new element as the parent, or just apply it to `body` in your case.

Then your `.defaultCalc` elements are not centered becasue they're block elements. You can either make them `inline-block` (what I did), or apply `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`

Your `header` element is also before `body` - it needs to be inside of `<body></body>`

```css
/*Base style layouts*/

header, body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #edf0f1;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 46px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 46px;
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44,62,80,0.15);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #95989A;
  text-align: center;
}

.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
}


/*Gray areas that display javascript calculations*/

.defaultCalc {
  border: 1px none;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}


/*Sections that require the user to input a number*/
.userInput::placeholder {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgba(149, 152, 154, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
}

.userInput {
  border: 1px solid #D3D8DB;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}


.sections {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

/*Buttons*/

.amButton,
.pmButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.calcButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 217px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.clockOutTime {
  border: 1px none;
  width: 133px;
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #60B6FF;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.clockOutAMButton,
.clockOutPMButton {
  border: 1px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #95989A;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
}

button:focus {outline:0;}

input:focus {
  border-color: #15D1BC;
  outline: none;
}

.pmButton:focus {
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.amButton:focus {
  background-color: #15D1BC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.calcButton:active {
  font-size: 1.075em;
}
```

```html
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,300i,400,400i,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

    <title>40 Hour Workweek Calculator</title>

</head>


<body>
<header>
  <h3>40-Hour Workweek Calculator</h3>
</header>
    <h4 class="sections">Total hours needed to work this week:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 40" />

    <h4 class="sections">On Friday morning, how many hours<br />(in whole numbers) do you currently have?</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 33"/>

    <h4 class="sections">Enter remaining decimals:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: .57"/>

    <h4 class="sections">Converted to time format:</h4>
      <div class="defaultCalc"></div>

    <h4 class="sections">Remaining hours to work:</h4>
      <div class="defaultCalc"></div>

    <h4 class="sections">Enter time you clocked in on Friday:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 7:22"/><br />

<div class="buttons">
    <button class="amButton">AM</button>
    <button class="pmButton">PM</button>
</div>

    <h4 class="sections">Enter today's lunch break in minutes:</h4>
      <input type="text" class="userInput" placeholder="ex: 30"/>

<div class="sections">
    <button class="calcButton">Calculate my hours</button>

<h4 class="sections">Time to clock out on Friday:</h4>
    <div class="defaultCalc clockOutTime"></div>

<div class="sections">
    <div class="clockOutAMButton">AM</div>
    <div class="clockOutPMButton">PM</div>
</div>

</body>
```